# Was Instagram, the first one who started using "insta" word

Tags: domains, keywords

I want to know, was Instagram the first one who started using "insta" word in domain name. There are so many other sites who started some word, and others followed their way for names. for eg Apple started i-something, myspace started mysomething, youtube started yousomething etc etc, I am not sure whether they were the first one, and invented the style of using them.

Answer (score 2):

No, there was: Instamatic (Kodak)

I cant think of any more right now but I'm sure they will come.